# Integrating with an array of upper limits Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The code for displacement is super slow. I'm looking for a more efficient way getting the values for s_soln. I have tried passing the tn3 array as the upper limit of quad but that doesn't seem to work.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, quad
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def fun(v, t, m, k, g):
    return (g*m - k*v**2)/m

#Velocity Plot
print 'Velocity Plot\n'

tn = np.linspace(0, 100, 1001)
v_soln = odeint(fun, 0, tn, args=(96, 0.2, 9.80665))

#Displacement Plot
tn3 = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
v = np.asarray(v_soln).squeeze()
v = interp1d(tn, v)
s_soln = []
for i in tn3:
    s_soln.append(list(quad(v, 0, i))[0])
s_soln = np.array(s_soln)

xvals = tn3
yvals = s_soln
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'))     
ax.plot(xvals, yvals)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('s(t)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable code. For example, what is `fun`?

Comment: Sorry, posted this late and didn't copy a lot of my code, I just edited it.

Comment: You may view the problem of finding the displacement `s` as the problem of solving a pair of first order D.E.s, namely `dv/dt=(g*m - k*v**2)/m` and `ds/dt = v` (w.r.t. `v` and `s`). This can be done directly by `odeint` following the lines of the example in the `odeint` [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure it out and I didn't fully understand the documentation. Could you explain a little more how to set up the system of first order D.E.s?

Comment: @Kklj8 Instead of the (`theta'(t)=...`, `omega'(t)=...`) system of equations in the doc. example, your system is (`v'(t)=(g*m - k*v**2)/m`,  `s'(t)=v(t)`). You should be able to do the appropriate changes in the doc. example so as to get the solution (with respect to `v` and `s`).

Comment: Finally figured it out! Thanks for the help.